# single-spa shared pinia store among Vue3 microapps

Tags: vuejs3, micro-frontend, pinia, single-spa

I'm setting up a microfrontends architecture with single-spa, vue3 and pinia.

I'm having some issue whereby I'm defining a store in a utiity microapp which gets imported in all other microapps.
In a microapp I'm then creating a pinia as a plugin and setting app.use(piniaPlugin).
Then in the microapp component I'm calling the useExportedStore() but this throws a pinia not found error.

Here some code snippets.

**single-spa-utils**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useGlobalState = defineStore('GlobalState', {
  id: 'GlobalState',
  state: () => ({
    currentRoute: '/',
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
});
```

**single-spa-microapp/main.js**

```
  import { globalStorePlugin } from "@/plugins/storesPlugins";

  const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  createApp,
  appOptions: {
    render() {
      return h(App, {});
    },
  },
  handleInstance: (app) => {
    console.log('>>> HANDLING INSTANCE APP')
    app.use(globalStorePlugin)
  },
});
```

**single-spa-microapp/storePlugins.js**

```
import { globalStore } from "@/stores/globalStore";

export const globalStorePlugin = {
  install: app => {
    console.log('globalStorePlugin :: installing globalStore pinia')
    app.use(globalStore);
  }
}
```

**single-spa-microapp/component.vue**

```
import { useGlobalState } from "@smart-inventory/smart-inventory-glob-lib";

const globalState = useGlobalState();
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
caught (in promise) Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
 const pinia = createPinia()
 app.use(pinia)

Comment: Your case is slightly different, single spa is against using state management across apps. See this: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#state-management

Comment: I have read single-spa recommends importing Vue as a shared resource.  It may apply to Pinia as well.  I don't know enough of Pinia to know for sure if it is bad to have copies of the library running concurrently in the same webpage.  Investigate about that.  Second, I suppose that every microapp that wants to access the shared store needs to do app.use(pinia).  Are you doing this?

Comment: @Forkmohit The same Problem here. Pinia is accessed before it is initialized. First the components are processed and then ```handleInstace``` is called. Is there already a workaround for this?